# How to query Database inside readstream

Tags: node.js, database

I am reading data from file having 30 million records through readstream in nodejs. Now I have to filter those record based on their status. their status is in database. so what i did i add database query inside readstream pipe. but after some queries database connection become unresponsive. Any idea or solution I can query database to check statues.

I am using nodejs and postgres with sequelize as orm. I am also using event-stream package as well.

es in code mean event-stream

```
   let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
        highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024,
    });
    
    
    
    fileStream.pipe(es.split()).pipe(
        es.mapSync(async function (line) {
            
            let extractData = line.split(",");
            let number = extractData[0];

            if (number) {
                count++;
             
                const status = await checkStatusInDatabase(number);
               
                if (status === "allow") {
       
                    addNumberIntoRedis(number).then(() => {
                        console.log("Process the number")
                    }).catch((error)=>{
                        console.log("error",error)
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    );
```

checkStatusInDatabase function check status database using findOne method of sequelize and after database check record is put into redis based on status

Comment: osama can you please add code of what you are doing.